# Why doesn't 'await' wait for axios request completes?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I tried to read HTTP response with axios and parse JSON in stream mode with stream-json` so I can fully fit my database on demand. It works well but if I try to **close database connection** everything will be crashed because the connection will be closed too soon.
*The problem is: await doesn't wait for the extract_coins function to complete (even if it's returning the promise) and close database connection in a final scope.*

```
const main = async() => {
   const dbcfg = config.get('db.coins');
   const db = await coins_db_configure(dbcfg);
   try {
      console.log('Connected to the database and created coins table!');

      await extract_coins('some_url_which_gives_correct_json', coins_emitter);
   }
   catch(e){
      console.error(e);
   }
   finally {
      await db.close();
   }
   };

main();
```

extract_coins:

```
module.exports = async function extract_coins(url, emitter){
    return await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
        responseType: 'stream'
    }).then((res) => {
        const pipeline = chain([
            res.data,
            parser(),
            pick({filter: 'data'}),
            streamArray()
        ]);
        pipeline.on('data', data => {
            emitter.emit('coin_extracted', data.value);
        });
        pipeline.on('end', () => console.log("All the coins were successfully passed!"));
    });
};
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything in your extract function.

Comment: You have asynchronous stuff happening with your pipeline, that is not promised-based, so that will not be awaited.

Comment: @Phix I return Promise and want await to understand that 'end' - event should make the promise fulfilled

Comment: @trincot, Just like you said, I deleted all of my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code related to the asynchronous `pipeline` is not promisified, you currently have no way to return a promise that resolves on getting the "end" event.

Your `await` *does* wait for the promise to resolve, but your `then` callback returns `undefined`, and so that resolves the promise at that very moment, long before the `end` event is broadcast.

So change this:

```
then((res) => {
    const pipeline = chain([
        res.data,
        parser(),
        pick({filter: 'data'}),
        streamArray()
    ]);
    pipeline.on('data', data => {
        emitter.emit('coin_extracted', data.value);
    });
    pipeline.on('end', () => console.log("All the coins were successfully passed!"));
});
```

To this:

```
then((res) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    const pipeline = chain([
        res.data,
        parser(),
        pick({filter: 'data'}),
        streamArray()
    ]);
    pipeline.on('data', data => {
        emitter.emit('coin_extracted', data.value);
    });
    pipeline.on('end', () => {
        console.log("All the coins were successfully passed!");
        resolve();
    });
}));
```

Comment: I've tried several promisifactions and yours too but now I'm getting another error: Connection Terminated and very slow execution of extract_coins. Why it works so fast and well without closing database connection?

Comment: If you remove the `try/catch`, then at which statement do you get the error? Which of the console.log takes a long time to appear? Are you sure you call `main` only once?

Comment: But, please understand that this is not the place for a progressive fix-debug session. I think I answered your question *"Why doesn't 'await' wait for axios request completes?"* I am willing to help though, so just thoroughly debug to give precise information. Possibly you'll need to ask a new question about the new problem...

Comment: You're right but neither db.close() nor extract_coins() cause Connection terminated error, it happens when I want to promisify function and resolve it in a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you used **ES6+** way but not in a common way, this causes this issue but, definitely, using `await` alongside `then` is exactly a fault, you should write them just like following codes:

```
const main = async () => {
   try {
     const dbcfg = config.get('db.coins');
     const db = await coins_db_configure(dbcfg);
     console.log('Connected to the database and created coins table!');
     await extract_coins('some_url_which_gives_correct_json', coins_emitter);

   } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);

   } finally {
      await db.close();

   }
};

main();
```

As you see, I put all of the codes inside `try` block, because using `async/await` means we pretend to write a *sync* code but it is `async` in fact, so we should put all codes, especially asynchronous lines inside `try` block. after putting them inside `try` block, just because of `async` flag behind of `()` JavaScript interpreter wait for each line to finish, if each line has error next lines won't run and interpreter falls into `catch` block, finally runs in all cases as you now.

Ok now back to the main issue, the **`extract_coins`** function:

```
export default (async function extract_coins(url, emitter) {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
      responseType: 'stream'
    });
    const pipeline = chain([
      res.data,
      parser(),
      pick({filter: 'data'}),
      streamArray()
    ]);
    await pipeline.on('data', data => {
      emitter.emit('coin_extracted', data.value);
    });
    await pipeline.on('end', () => console.log("All the coins were successfully passed!"));
    // HERE: return what you want

  } catch (e) {
    throw e;

  }

});
```

This is the cause of the issue, you should pass the promise of `extract_coins` function with the new EcmaScript method, not using callback functions.

If I wan in your place I would write the `extract_coins` like below:

```
const extract_coins = async (url, emitter) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
      responseType: 'stream'
    });
    const pipeline = chain([
      res.data,
      parser(),
      pick({filter: 'data'}),
      streamArray()
    ]);
    await pipeline.on('data', data => {
      emitter.emit('coin_extracted', data.value);
    });
    await pipeline.on('end', () => console.log("All the coins were successfully passed!"));
    // HERE: return what you want

  } catch (e) {
    throw e;

  }

};

export default extract_coins;
```

Comment: A small question about how can you define `db` inside a try scope while you're trying to use it inside finally scope. I don't think it's correct because `config.get()` function can throw an exception and finally scope will not work correct way because `db` variable wouldn't exist.